# How to measure the content of an article

Tags: parsing, methods

I was wondering what the best approach to measure the content of an article, and decide if that article had a positive or negative approach.

A couple of friends and me have been discussing this for a time now, and is looking forward to see what the guys on stackoverflow comes up with. (We all agree on the basic method, that you have to parse the article one by one, and then decide, but it's the how that's the problem).

Thanks!

Lars

Comment: Can you give examples for _positive_ and _negative_ articles, please? Isn't that subjective?

Comment: Does your question have a postive or negative approach and why?

Comment: Hmm, I can see that, but there must be some kind of common denominator for positive and negative articles, this could be keywords that each article was matched against.

Comment: Ever heard of _[passive aggressive](http://www.passiveaggressivenotes.com/)_? Is that positive or negative?

Comment: I'm not looking for a debate on what is positive and what is negative, but merely an approach to accomplish some kind of judging/measurement of an article.

Comment: @Lars: I believe what the other commenters are trying to point out is that how you define "positive" and "negative" may determine how this problem is solved. While it is likely that a parser of some kind will be used it is the semantic analysis that is going to be the hairy part if you are trying to determine the tone. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing

Comment: This type of NLP is called "sentiment analysis" and yes subjective information can be extracted from text. Don't humans understand when someone is critical even when he's being sarcastic? What's positive or negative is certainly subjective, but understanding when a writer is being positive or negative is far less so.  Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis as a start.